# how to use font awesome in own css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm using bootstrap and Font Awesome. In a custom css class I'm working on I tried to include Font Awesome icons instead of using images. Here is my code before Font Awesome.

```
.data .close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../img/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

.next:hover {
  background: url(../img/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
}
```

Here is my code using Font Awesome, which obviously doesn't work. The icons don't show. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
.data .close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: FontAwesome
  content: "\f00d";
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}


.next {
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}

.next:hover {
  font-family: FontAwesome
  content: "\f054";
}
```

html header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>

....

....
```

[here is a fiddle of what i'm working on](http://jsfiddle.net/hRvZR/).

Comment: where did you define `FontAwesome` ? Can you show also your HTML head ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can do so by using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo. read more about it here http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

change your code to this

```
.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.lb-prev:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f053";
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

do the same for the other icons. you might want to adjust the color and height of the icons too. anyway here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRvZR/4/) hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

The spirit of Web font is to use cache as much as possible, therefore you should use CDN version between `<head></head>` instead of hosting yourself:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, make sure you loaded your CSS **AFTER** the above line, or your custom font CSS won't work.

Reference: [Font Awesome Get Started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)

Comment: what if i put my css and font-awesome in the same css. css files and js files are cached on my server too

Comment: it's okay, but the cache cannot share with only people using the same CSS. By the way, is your issue resolved ?

Comment: nope, sill doesn't work. the images don't show. i'm basically trying to use font awesome with http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid issue description. Any error? And missing files? Check Developer console.

Comment: no errors, just image doesn't show.  i'm basically trying to use font awesome with lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2

Comment: didn't i include it in the "External Resources" on the left ? http://jsfiddle.net/hRvZR/1/

Comment: who downvote this? the image is now displaying correctly, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

**Instructions for Drupal 8 / FontAwesome 5**

Create a YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE.THEME file and place it in your themes directory (ie. your_site_name/themes/your_theme_name)

Paste this into the file, it is PHP code to find the Search Block and change the value to the UNICODE for the FontAwesome icon. You can find other characters at this link https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet.

```
<?php
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
}
?>
```

Open the CSS file of your theme (ie. your_site_name/themes/your_theme_name/css/styles.css) and then paste this in which will change all input submit text to FontAwesome. Not sure if this will work if you also want to add text in the input button though for just an icon it is fine.

Make sure you import FontAwesome, add this at the top of the CSS file

```
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css');
```

then add this in the CSS

```
input#edit-submit {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;  
}
```

**FLUSH ALL CACHES AND IT SHOULD WORK FINE**

***Add Google Font Effects***

If you are using Google Web Fonts as well you can add also add effects to the icon (see more here https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#enabling_font_effects_beta). You need to import a Google Web Font including the effect(s) you would like to use first in the CSS so it will be

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800&effect=3d-float');
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css');
```

Then go back to your .THEME file and add the class for the 3D Float Effect so the code will now add a class to the input. There are different effects available. So just choose the effect you like, change the CSS for the font import and the change the value FONT-EFFECT-3D-FLOAT int the code below to font-effect-WHATEVER_EFFECT_HERE. Note effects are still in Beta and don't work in all browsers so read here before you try it https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#enabling_font_effects_beta

```
<?php
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'font-effect-3d-float';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
In your css file change `font-family: FontAwesome` into `font-family: "FontAwesome";` or `font-family: 'FontAwesome';`. I've solved the same problem using this method.