# How do you include a Font Awesome icon in your sass file?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

How do you use the `@include` to use a Font awesome icon in you sass file.

E.g - If I wanted to use this icon:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/pencil/

I understand that you can use it in your HTML like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
```

However I want to be able to do the following or something similar:

```
.class-name {
    @include: fa-icon(fa-pencil);
}
```

What is the default/proper way to do this?

Comment: There already is a thread which could help you with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179098/how-to-use-font-awesome-in-own-css

Comment: This is not quite how I want to be able to do it, I want to be able to use the mixin. By the looks of it I might have to use a custom mixin as it doesn't look like I can do it how I want by default

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if anyone will find this helpful but I created a mixin that extended the `.fa` class rather than editing the existing `@mixin fa-icon()`

**Custom Mixin**

```
@mixin icon($icon) {
    @include fa-icon;
    @extend .fa;
    @extend .fa-#{$icon}:before;
}
```

**Usage**

```
.foo:before {
    @include icon(pencil);
}
```

*Where 'pencil' is the name of the icon referenced here (minus the `fa-`): https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/*

**Update for Font Awesome 5:**

```
@mixin icon($icon) {
  @include fa-icon;
  @extend .fas;
  @extend .fa-#{$icon};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is to use [@extend](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7).

In you case:

```
.class-name {
    @extend: .fa-pencil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working it out. There are a couple of ways to do it both very similar:

**Option one**

Edit the existing `@mixin fa-icon()` by adding a parameter into it e.g it would look like this:

```
@mixin fa-icon($icon) {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal #{$fa-font-size-base}/1 FontAwesome; // shortening font declaration
  font-size: inherit; // can't have font-size inherit on line above, so need to override
  text-rendering: auto; // optimizelegibility throws things off #1094
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0); // ensures no half-pixel rendering in firefox
  @extend .fa;
  @extend .fa-#{$icon};

}
```

**Usage:**

```
.class-name {
    @include fa-icon(facebook);
    font-size: 50px;    
}
```

---

**Option 2:**

Use this custom mixin: http://genesy.me/font-awesome-mixin/

Answer (score 0):

@import "path_name/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";

```
.class-name{
    &::before {
      @include fa-icon;
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
      content: fa-content($fa-var-pencil);
    }
}
```

in fontawesome.scss : the mixin @include fa-icon put all properties 
necessary for icon.

in variables.scss of fontawesome the function fa-content format font code for unquote :

in varaibles.scss each icon has a variable content her code like pencil
    $fa-var-pencil: \f040;

Just add font family :
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; or
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; or 
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 solid"; or 
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 regular"; or
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 light"; or 
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 brands"; or

for see all fonts available look into webfonts directory of fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

As of Font Awesome 5.x, implementers using the npm package ([@fortawesome/fontawesome-free](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/v/5.1.0-9)) can achieve this by leveraging the SCSS files included as part of that distribution:

```
/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/
```

#### Relevant Files

- `_mixins.scss`: Provides a `fa-icon` mixin with the base styles required.
- `_variables.scss`: Provides variables for each icon corresponding to their unicode character (e.g., `$fa-var-stack-overflow` maps to `\f16c`).
- `regular.scss`, `solid.scss`, &c.: Provides `@font-face` declarations for each font.

#### Implementation

First, import the appropriate files:

```
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/_mixins.scss";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
```

Then, for your actual classes, include the `fa-icon` mixin, the appropriate font family, and the variable for the icon you wish to implement:

```
.selector {
  &::before {
    @include fa-icon;
    font-family               : 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    content                   : fa-content($fa-var-stack-overflow);
  }
}
```

> *Note:* The `fa-content()` function is part of `_variables.scss` and wraps the unicode output in quotes.

#### Limitations

The font family names for the free versions of both *Regular* and *Solid* are the same ("Font Awesome 5 Free"), thus introducing ambiguity if you want to mix icons from both font sets. If that's the case, you'll likely need to create your own font declaration for *Solid* in order to disambiguate the name.

#### Credits and Further Reading

- [CSS Pseudo-elements](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements), from Font Awesome, describes how to manually construct CSS classes which covers the underlying concepts used here.
- [@Christophe-Gougeon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383601/3025856) covers the same basic material—though I felt the approach merited a bit more careful and detailed instruction.
- [@Peter-J-Harrison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36285419/3025856) provides a useful mixin which further simplifies the syntax.